# Who is Astra Space Inc and what is their DARPA-funded rocket they are planning on launching later this year?

Tags: smallsat-launcher

[image]

All of a sudden, I'm hearing about a new company called [Astra](https://www.bloomberg.com/features/2020-astra-rocket/) (not Ad Astra). They've got some nice pictures in that article linked but I can't find any information about their launch site, engines, fuels, tankage, or even staging online, besides that the main tank is some sort of aluminum alloy.

[image]

From what I gather, it's got two stages & at least five engines (seems very similar to Rutherfords if not actually Rutherfords), but I don't have any sort of source for that. [Even Gunter isn't sure!](https://space.skyrocket.de/doc_lau/astra.htm)

What is Astra's rocket? In particular, what engines & stages is it using?

Answer (score 1):

The best source of information right now is from an [interview with Bloomberg](https://www.bloomberg.com/features/2020-astra-rocket/). Some key things:

The rocket is actually named Astra, built by Astra. There are 5 engines on the first stage, which are custom built engines for this purpose, and they have no name that I can figure out.

It looks like it is a 2 stage rocket, but I can't find any definitive information. Still, it seems right, and is what Gunter also predicts, I would be surprised if it was anything else.

The company was called the "Stealth Rocket Company" for a long time, and they have held to it.

Comment: Stealth mode has ended! Would you like to augment your answer by quoting from [this](https://spaceflightnow.com/2020/02/24/fresh-out-of-stealth-mode-astra-gearing-up-for-orbital-launch-from-alaska/) and [this](https://www.space.com/astra-first-darpa-launch-challenge-weather-delay.html) perhaps? If not, I might be able to write a new answer, though I'm no expert in stuff like this.